# Java, работа с элементами массива

Tags: java, массивы

Нужно создать массив произвольной длины с целыми числами и произвести следующие действия:

Если элементы меньше заданного числа, замените их этим числом. Сделать это нужно, как отдельный метод, который будет вызываться из main.

Сам массив:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );

    int[] array = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Как написать метод замены?

```
public static int[] smallerNumbers(int[] array( ? ? ? ), int b) {

    for (int each: array) {
        if (each < b) {
            each = b;
        }
        return ? ? ?
    }
}
```

Comment: использовать цикл `for`, а не `for-each`  и вы сами все поймете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
public static int[] smallerNumbers(int[] array, int b) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < b) {
            array[i] = b;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int each: array) {
    if (each < b) {
        each = b;
    }
```

В данном блоке вы изменяете не сам массив, а переменную "each", т.е. после выполнения цикла массив "array" не изменится, для того, чтобы изменить его используйте следующую конструкцию:

```
for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (array[index] < b) {
        array[index] = b;
    }
}
```

А затем вам надо вернуть ИЗМЕНЕННЫЙ массив:

```
return array;
```